# Manifold of lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, manifolds

From [1, pag. 106] we learn that the set of all lines in in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a $4$-$D$ manifold $\mathcal{S}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^6$:

Consider a space line $L$. Let $H$ be the point on $L$ closest to the coordinate origin $O$, and put $\boldsymbol{r}_H=\overrightarrow{O H}$. Let $\boldsymbol{m}$ be the unit vector that indicates the orientation of $L$. The space line $L$ is represented by two 3-vectors $\left\{\boldsymbol{m}, \boldsymbol{r}_H\right\}$; two representations $\left\{\boldsymbol{m}, \boldsymbol{r}_H\right\}$ and $\left\{-\boldsymbol{m}, \boldsymbol{r}_H\right\}$ define the same space line. A space point $\boldsymbol{r}$ is on $L$ if and only if vector $\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_H$ is parallel to $\boldsymbol{m}$, or
$$
\left(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_H\right) \times \boldsymbol{m}=\mathbf{0},
$$
which is simply the equation of space line $L$ if $\boldsymbol{r}$ is regarded as a variable. Two 3-vectors $\left\{\boldsymbol{m}, \boldsymbol{r}_H\right\}$ represent a space line if and only if
$$
\|\boldsymbol{m}\|=1, \quad\left(\boldsymbol{m}, \boldsymbol{r}_H\right)=0,
$$
where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the scalar product.

Now my question is: is $\mathcal{S}$ some well known manifold with a name? I am working on a problem where the position of a line in space has to be optimized and I would like to use manifold optimization techniques. I assume, for example, that $\mathcal{S}$ has a Lie Algebra, etc.

[1] Kanatani, K. (2005). Statistical Optimization for Geometric Computation. Dover Publications.

Comment: Please read about [Grassmanians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian).

Comment: Since I am interested in the case of lines in general position (not necessarily going through the origin), maybe $\mathcal{S}$ is more precisely an [Affine Grassmannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_Grassmannian_(manifold)) ?

Comment: @ArrigoBenedetti You accepted an answer that is clearly false since the dimension does not match. You are right that it is the Grassmanian of affine lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is $\mathbb {RP}^2 \times \mathbb R^2$.

$\mathbb {RP}^2$ is for the line orientation noted $m$ (unit vector) in the OP. I first wrongly commented it was $S^2$, but we take the quotient by the equivalence relation $m \sim -m$. This is the definition of the real projective space, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space (where all non-null orientation vectors are considered, and quotient is by $m \sim \lambda m$ for all $\lambda \ne 0$).
$\mathbb {RP}^2$ is also the Grassmanian $\mathbf {Gr} (1, \mathbb R^3)$ (same Wikipedia page).

Then $\times \mathbb R^2$ is for the translation by $r_H$.

As $\mathbb {RP}^2$ can be embedded in $\mathbb R^4$ (see same Wikipedia page), $\mathbb {RP}^2 \times \mathbb R^2$ can be embedded in $\mathbb R^6$.

Comment: The right answer definitely is a vector bundle over $\Bbb RP^2$, but do you have a proof that it is a trivial one?

Comment: @Didier It depends upon the structure one puts upon this set of lines. The OP says the space line is represented by $\{m; r_H\}$. Then it follows that it is the product of what represents $m$ and what represents $r_H$. There are probably other ways to represent this set of lines, although I don't see any currently.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez It depends upon the usage. I understand what you propose in comment to the OP. Both our proposals however have a drawback: they are not consistent with the "distance" between $2$ lines (actually not a distance, because not separated) and it lets the origin play a specific role. A more natural topology on lines could be this pseudometric space generated by line distance. It would not be separated, but the induced topology would be invariant upon rotation and translation of the base referential.

Comment: @ArrigoBenedetti Still another possibility: take $2$ different points in $\mathbb R^3$; that's equivalent to a point in $E$ $= \mathbb R^6$ less $\{(x_i)_{i=1}^6, x_1=x_4, x_2=x_5, x_3=c_6\}$. Then quotient by the relation "the $2$ pairs of points define the same line", where each pair of points is an element of $E$. That one may be more respectful of invariance by translation and rotation of the base referential.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I mean, when $2$ lines have a null pseudo-distance (they cross on a point), their distance in $\mathbb {RP} ^2 \times \mathbb R^2$ or in what you propose (if I understand it correctly) can be arbitrarily high. Moreover it depends upon the chosen origin, which would be bad in physics for example, where independance from the referential frame is sought after.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I don't mind recognizing that another solution is better. But so far I don't see how you would define $q$ in a consistent manner accross tangent planes at each $p$, without avoiding discontinuities at some point $p$: sphere $S^2$ is not parallelizable (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable_manifold). Please, you could write your solution as an answer.